# What is the purpose of R1, R2 in this ESD protection circuit

Tags: esd, transceiver

What is the purpose of R1 and R2 in this circuit? Is it required? I have seen in documents like https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8169-D.PDF where no resistors are shown in the example protection circuits.

[image]

Comment: I believe these resistors limit the current into or out of the grey block particularly when the voltages at pins A and B lie outside the supply rails (during an ESD event)...

Answer (score 5):

Those buffer the protected pin from the ESD event while ESD diodes do their job since it takes a finite amount of time for them to do so. It is similar to placing the ESD diodes as close to the connector as possible and as far away from protected pin as possible which uses the parasitic inductance of the traces instead of a resistor. Ferrite beads can also be used.

One way to look at it is that they limit the ESD current that flows into the pin (and then through the internal ESDs or rail clamp diodes or capacitances) due to the ESD diodes not being perfect clamps and taking a finite amount of time to clamp. They also work with the input capacitance (either internal or added) as a filter to limit any voltage "spillover" from the clamping of the ESD diodes.

Answer (score 0):

The IEC air gap test (150pF 330Ω) is far more severe than the HBM test (100pF 1.5kΩ), yet far less repeatable due to the faster rise times.

The TVS and XCVR both have low capacitance but the 10 ohm series R reduces the current sharing of this capacitance during a 1kV to 8kV transient rapid rise time.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd78.pdf

TI has updated has evolved their App. Note to improve protection even further.
 [image]
Next, *someone* can check if ON Semi has done the same.
Perhaps you are dealing with an evolution of immunity improvements and outdated documents.